# RubyMine-7.1.4 IDE is breaking in MAC OS 10.12

Tags: java, macos, rubymine-7

Following are the needed configuration details,

Java Version - 9.0.4

MAC OS Version - 10.12

RubyMine - 7.1.4

When I am clicking on RubyMine IDE, its breaking and giving errors,

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : sun/misc/resource

I have googled it and tried to apply solution to set "JAVA_HOME" variable path, but still its breaking.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, it was an issue of Java version.
I have installed Java version 1.6 and added to ~/.bash_profile [and for zsh shell add it to ~/.profile file]

> export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)"

After restarting PC, Rubymine is started working.